# XMLSchema - Choice + Element with at least one element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a xml schema that allows the following:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="A" />
        <xs:element ref="B" />
        <xs:element ref="C" />
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

This means I can create an element of 0 or more of (A or B or C) and after that 0 or 1 of (D). Like

```
<A/><B/><A/><D>
```

or

```
<A/><B/><A/>
```

or

```
<A/><C/><B/><A/>
```

I want to add another constraint: There must be at least one (A or B or C or D).

Can that constraint be expressed by xsd?

Comment: *this means i can make a elements of 1 ore more of (A or B or C)*  No, it means **0** or more of A, B, or C.  Which do you actually want for that part of your question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited this. 0 or more.

Comment: Another questions: If the choice had no minOccurs="0". Would that mean, that at least one A,B or C are necessary?

Comment: Yes, the default for `xs:choice/@minOccurs` is 1.

Comment: Okay, then my question remains at is it. I need at least one elements but I have everywhere minOccurs="0".

Comment: You'll need XSD 1.1's support for assertions if you want to express your constraint in XSD.